# How to handle coroutine when using tornado websockets

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio, tornado, nonblocking

I'm using tornado websockets and it works fine.

However, I'd like to listen for changes to a MongoDB Collection and send new changes to the websocket client.

I cannot get it running with threads, and I saw that using threads with tornado is discouraged.

I'm really stuck right now. How can I proceed?

(blocking) Code right now:

```
    def open(self):
        print("Opening Connection")
        with self.collection.watch() as stream:
            for change in stream:
                doc = change["fullDocument"]
                self.write_message(u"%s" % json.dumps(doc))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Motor can handle Mongodb changestreams. https://motor.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-asyncio/asyncio_motor_change_stream.html

Personally, I find [RethinkDB](https://rethinkdb.com/api/python/set_loop_type/) or [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) are better alternatives for realtime features like this. But without knowing your needs, I cannot say if this is a good for you.